# Robot-C Slow Down Motor (Tetrix)

Tags: nxt, robotc

So I want to slow down a motor on a Tetrix Robot:

Here's my code:

```
//Makes the main frame of arm move up and down  

    motor[motorE] = joystick.joy1_y2 ;
```

How can I make the values given by `joystick.joy1_y2`slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the programmer on an FTC Team and we use RobotC, like it appears you are using. If you are, you can just divide the joystick.joy1_y2 by some other value for instance:

```
motor[motorE] = (joystick.joy1_y2/2);
```

And you could make that adjustable by using something like:

```
int motorDivide = 1;

task motorTask;

task main(){

    StartTask(motorTask);

    while(true){
       getJoystickSettings(joystick);
    }

}

task motorTask(){
    while(true){

        if (joy1Btn(1) == 1){
            motorDivide+=1;
            if (motorDivide >= 3){
                motorDivide = 1;
            }
            wait1Msec(100);
        }

        motor[motorE] = (joystick.joy1_y2/motorDivide);
    }
}
```